# How can i display the text message from MVC to Javascript and preserve the carriage return line feed?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I return a string in the c# MVC controller as follows:

```
 Errors in message\r\nFirstName must be filled\r\nLastName must be filled
```

When i do a quick watch on this it shows as

```
      Errors in message
      FirstName must be filled
      LastName must be filled
```

Which is fine.

I then send this to my AngularJS Javascript controller and the \r\n are not preserved and it display the  text as follows:

```
   Errors in messageFirstName must be filledLastName must be filled
```

How can i preserve the text formatting ?

Comment: If you're rendering the text to an element other than a `<textarea>`, you'll need to replace the `\r\n` with `<br>` elements.

Comment: thanks . I used replace(/\n/g, "<br />");